# calling methods with parameters

Tags: methods

```
class Robot extends Canvas
{
   public Robot()    //constructor method - sets up the class
   {
      setSize(800,600);
      setBackground(Color.WHITE);       
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public void paint( Graphics window )
   {
      window.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      window.drawString("Robot LAB ", 35, 35 );




      //call head method

      //call other methods

   }

   public void head( Graphics window )
   {
      window.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      window.fillRect(300, 100, 200, 100);


        //add more code here

   }
```

How exactly do I call the head method?

I've tried multiple times, but I just can't seem to get it.

head(); window.head(); hasn't worked for me?

Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: How about `head(window);` ?

Comment: Thanks! head(window); worked for me, but may I know why you put window in the brackets? What normally goes in the brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
head(window);
```

This is just how you call a method with parameters in Java (and most other languages), you put the parameters as a comma-separated list in the parentheses that follow the method name. Note that the parantheses are there even without any parameters.

```
methodWithNoParameters();
someOtherObject.methodWithNoParameters();
this.methodWithOneParameter("foo");
SomeClass.staticMethodWithFiveParameters(1,two,3,4, "five");
```

The number, order and types of the parameters must match what the method declaration has for its formal parameters. In your case `public void(Graphics window)` means there is just one.

Finally, you should make this method `private` if you only call it from inside `paint` (and not from outside of the class itself).